# Javascript string replace() method malfunctioning for dots and commas

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a text by using the user input values but for the below script dots and commas are malfunctioning when replacing. I tried `(/\x/)` method but it's not working, maybe because it's a value. So, how can I execute output more accurately?

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var x = new RegExp(document.getElementById("x").value, "g");
    var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
    var txt = str.replace(x, y);

    document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = txt;
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById("text").value = "";
}
```

example:

```
text = ..........a.a.a..a..a..aaaaaa..a.a. 
x = ..a 
y = B 
output = ........B.BBBBBaaB.a.
```

but output should be

```
 ........B.a.aBBBaaaaaB.a.
```

(Sorry for the unprofessional example...)

I am just now learning JS and not a professional and I'm trying to make a replacer web page using JS like in MS Notepad where you can press <kbd>ctrl+H</kbd> and replace any word or letter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! (Please take the introductory [tour] some time.) Can you add some example input and output, along with what you intended to get?

Comment: example : 
text = ..........a.a.a..a..a..aaaaaa..a.a. 
x = ..a
y = B

output = ........B.BBBBBaaB.a.
but output should be = ........B.a.aBBBaaaaaB.a.

//sorry for the unprofessional example :(

Comment: Yeah well, please use [edit] to add it to your post.

Comment: Thanks I've added. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `RegExp.escape`, unlucky for you - the smart people at the JavaScript technical committee decided to [postpone its inclusion](https://github.com/benjamingr/RegExp.escape/issues/37) in the standard because of an edge case you, or anyone else will likely never run into.

```
if(!RegExp.escape){
    RegExp.escape = function(s){
      return String(s).replace(/[\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    };
}
```

Then, you can call it on a value and it'll escape it for use in `new RegExp`:

```
var raw = document.getElementById("x").value;
var x = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(raw), "g");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this regex - [.]{2}[a] or [.][.][a].

Two dots mandatory with trailing a. And it should be of 3 characters.